# Sending Laravel 5.1 validation response back to Smarty template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, smarty, laravel-5.1

I am creating an addon to an existing website using Laravel 5.1.  The existing website uses Smarty as opposed to Blade templating system.

I have Laravel installed and working perfectly well.  However, when I create a `Request` validator it doesn't send the `$_SESSION['message']` value back to the page.

For example if I fill out a form but leave a required field blank, Laravel sends the user back to the page an displays some errors to tell the user to fill in the blank required field.  However, I can't manage to get the error displaying on the page.

Here is my controller:

```
/**
 * Add new project.
 *
 * @param AddNewProjectRequest $request
 * @return Redirect
 */
public function add(AddNewProjectRequest $request) 
{
    // Create new project
    $project = $this->project->add($request->only('name', 'number', 'builder', 'overall_budget', 'start_date', 'end_date'));

    // Event(s);
    Event::fire(new ProjectAdded($project, $request->only('file')));

    // Redirect user
    return redirect('../superusers/projectAdded');
}
```

And here is the part of my Smarty template that needs to display the error:

```
{if $smarty.session.message}
    <div class="alert alert-success">
    <ul>
        <li>{$smarty.session.message}</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

as per Laravel, whenever it returns with errors, you can do this. this is blade template standards

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
  @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
    {{ $error }}
  @endforeach
@endif
```